# WiX command-line option for no UI, '/quiet', kills the running process

Tags: command-line, wix, installation, windows-installer

I have created a setupkit with no UI using Wix for my application (called "XYZ" here).

If I double click the MSI while XYZ.exe is runnning, it notifies me that a process is locking a file: I can choose to kill the locking process or I can abort the installation.
This is fine: as a user I can decide what to do.

But when I run the same MSI from the commandline,

msiexec /i XYZ.msi /quiet /norestart

if `XYZ.exe` is found running it will be killed. This is absolutely inacceptable in my scenario: the MSI should abort the installation and exit.

The same setupkit works as expected if I set a "Mondo" interface (or any other interface).

What is the solution?

Comment: from what I have understood it seems that the problem is related to the Restart Manager component...
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/12/11/windows-installer-and-restart-manager-msi-files-in-use-v2.aspx

Answer (score 7):

The article you linked to says Restart Manager shuts down the running processes to mitigate reboot, and it should start the process after setup is complete. It also mentions which properties control the interaction with Restart Manager:

[**`MSIRMSHUTDOWN`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370380.aspx) when set to `2`:

> Processes or services that are currently using files affected by the update are shut down only if they have all been registered for a restart. If any process or service has not been registered for a restart, then no processes or services are shut down.

Ensure [`MSIDISABLERMRESTART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370089.aspx) has value of `0`. In this case Restart Manager will restart all the processes and services it shut down.

See also [`MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370377.aspx)

---

If you disable shutting down of running processes, the installation *would not fail*: it would succeed and Windows Installer will initiate system restart to complete the update. You can use `/norestart` option to suppress reboot. Yet it is *recommended* to reboot as soon as possible because the system is not in a consistent state.

Thus it's better to teach your process to communicate with Restart Manager so that reboot is mitigated.

Comment: Alexey thanx for your response...
What I really can't understand is why the same MSI (or MSI created using WIX?) works in two really different flavours when I run it from commandline (using same /quiet /norestart flags)...

1. Msi with a UI (Mondo or anything else) --> installation fails, no process is killed
2. Msi with no UI --> installation succeed and processes are killed 

In my scenario if the application is running it's absolutely inacceptable that the MSI could try to change the system.

Comment: How does installation fail when it's run with UI? And what buttons do you click in the UI? In non-UI mode, its behavior seems to be correct, I don't have much experience with Restart Manager. Try to set `MSIRMSHUTDOWN` to `2`, and `MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL` to `Disable` or `DisableShutdown`. In non-UI you can't display any messages to user where you can explain why the installation failed.

Comment: Sorry for this delay... I'll try to clarify. MSI "A" created using Wix with Mondo UI; MSI "B" created using Wix, but with no UI. Both started from commandline whit "/quiet /norestart" args. Under the same conditions (a file is locked) "A" fails while "B" succeed and kills running processes. unfortunately your solution doesn't work...

Comment: How does "A" fail? What is in the msi logs? How do logs differ in either case? Does setting `MSIRMSHUTDOWN` and/or `MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL` have any impact on the behavior?