# Windows Installer kills Explorer process during an MSI update, but doesn't restart it

Tags: windows-installer, explorer

I've noticed that if you have an MSI package that installs and registers DLLs as Explorer extensions then try to install an update for that package, Windows Installer may kill Explorer then fail to restart it after the update is installed. It may only occur when using the msiexec "/quiet" option.

Is this a known problem? Is there a workaround for this? I've searched through the verbose msiexec logs and failed to come up with a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: See also this question: [Wix “no ui” /quiet kills running process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354767/wix-no-ui-quiet-kills-running-process)

Comment: This is something I've noticed regularly on test/dev machines, happening up to 5% of the time. However on production or customer machines it's closer to 0.02% or less

Comment: This happens for me with non-quiet setups as well. Manually starting Explorer after it has been killed triggers Explorer flickering in a restart loop.

Answer (score 0):

Old post I know but I've returned back to StackOverflow.

Is the original base installer installing a shell extension? Is the update package trying to overwrite previous files? Applying update MSP packages can often break you're system if not applied or chained correctly. Adversely, ensure all important updates have been applied to your system correctly.

The issue will be either a virus/malware or incorrect updates applied / required patches haven't applied in correct order etc. Re-installing Windows or going to a prior healthy restore point could be an option also.