# wix Restart Manager successfully shuts down application but says it couldn't

Tags: wix, windows-installer, major-upgrade, wix3.11, restartmanager

In my wix project, I have a file "connect.exe" that will usually be running during uninstall or update. During uninstallation and major update Wix will prompt before closing with the usual "The following applications should be closed before continuing the install."

This dialogue *will* successfully shut down the program:

```
Action 17:19:59: ShutdownApplications. Shutting down applications
MSI (s) (5C:44) [17:20:02:880]: RESTART MANAGER: Successfully shut down all applications in the service's session that held files in use.
MSI (c) (A4:08) [17:20:02:880]: RESTART MANAGER: Successfully shut down all applications that held files in use.
```

But then right after, it'll throw an error saying that it could not shut down the application:

```
MSI (s) (5C:44) [17:20:33:300]: Note: 1: 1611 
MSI (s) (5C:44) [17:20:33:300]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (5C:44) [17:20:33:300]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1611 
The setup was unable to automatically close all requested applications. Please ensure that the applications holding files in use are closed before continuing with the installation.
```

Even though the application is clearly shut down on the system. Also, it won't restart it when doing a major update after the installer is finished updating.

Everything else seems to work just fine.

Notably, the program connect.exe runs a window that is hidden *most* of the time. It's mainly used as an on screen display for service.exe which runs via Windows System Service.

How can I fix this to work? Am I not handling something on the connect.exe application end?

**connect.exe** component entry:

```
            <Component Id="ConnectExe" Guid="..." DiskId="1">
                <File Id="connect.exe" Name="connect.exe" Source="..\data\connect.exe" KeyPath="yes">
                    <Shortcut Advertise="yes" Description="Connect front end application." Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Icon="connect.exe" Id="ConnectStartMenuShortcut" Name="Connect" IconIndex="0" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR">
                        <Icon Id="connect.exe" SourceFile="..\data\connect.exe" />
                    </Shortcut>
                    <Shortcut Advertise="yes" Description="Connect front end application." Directory="StartupFolder" Icon="connect.exe" IconIndex="0" Id="ConnectStartupShortcut" Name="Connect" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"></Shortcut>
                </File>
                <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall" />
            </Component>
```

Comment: Does the application properly follow restart manager protocol? For restart manager to work, the application needs to handle certain messages and do this in a timely fashion. For instance, if it spends too much time handling `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` / `WM_ENDSESSION`, restart manager will consider it as not responding, which could lead to the error message you see. Also, if the application did not register itself for restart, restart manager won't restart the application. See [Guidelines for Applications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/RstMgr/guidelines-for-applications).

Comment: I have the exact same problem with the exact same log entries, but in my case I’m updating a shell extension. So it’s not my program that fails to restart, it’s explorer.exe. Makes it unlikely that Restart Manager protocol is not followed.

Comment: @Krishty - did you resolve how to get WiX to successfully install and uninstall shell extensions? I am really struggling and can't find any good examples on the web. It shuts down explorer.exe, but fails to restart it.

Comment: @TimCalladene No. The problem persisted even with manually-built MSIs (no WiX involved). My impression is that this is no bug in either WiX nor the MSIs, but MS screwed this up big time in the Installer service, in Restart Manager, or in Explorer. I resorted to making reboots mandatory for my shell extensions … bad for the user, but I’m out of ideas.

Comment: @Krishty - I did some more experimenting and did get a resolution of sorts. See my own answer to this question I posted a few days ago: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71158991/wix-how-to-restart-windows-explorer-to-install-uninstall-a-shell-extension

Comment: @TimCalladene Thanks, but this is not acceptable to me because I must be sure my shell extension is loaded properly. May be interesting for others, though, so upvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Improved?***: [**Different ways to create and interpret MSI logs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890).

---

> ***Log File***: What does the rest of the log file say? Any mention of other files that are locked? [**Some logging and log-file interpretation hints can be found here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026782/website-is-not-getting-created-in-iis-limited-edition-of-installshield/49028367#49028367).

I wouldn't be surprised if you have found a bug in the restart manager. Though a relatively simple concept, it involves some seriously complicated stuff. **Hidden windows** are exactly a source of such complexity.

***Quick Questions***:

- Do you **shut down the service executable** you refer to as well? Maybe it is installed by a different setup? You can set it to shut down and restart on installation.
- I assume you have implemented the proper **restart manager support in your application**?

  - The [**`Advanced Installer`**](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) guys have a very nice, technical article about this: [**`How do I add support for Windows Restart Manager to my application?`**](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-vista-restart-manager.html)
  - [PhilDW explains the gist of implementing **restart manager** support here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36776196/129130).
  - And [my own attempt to explain restart manager can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917062/windows-installer-avoid-fileinuse-dialog-box-when-installing-a-package/50935008#50935008) (**scroll down for middle colored section**).
- Given that you have implemented restart manager support, you do **register a tested command line to restart the application** after the installation completes?

---

***Some Links***:

- [In-use files not updated by MSI-installer (Visual Studio Installer project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385973/in-use-files-not-updated-by-msi-installer-visual-studio-installer-project/51458890)
- [Windows Installer-Avoid FileinUse dialog box when Installing a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917062/windows-installer-avoid-fileinuse-dialog-box-when-installing-a-package/50935008#50935008)
- [Restart Manager behavior with windows installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767411/restart-manager-behavior-with-windows-installer)

Comment: This answer is pretty phenomenal. My application is built on Qt. But I am listening for both WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION events. The application doesn't get *either* of them. The tray icon disappears, but my application does not stop running. Not sure what other messages are being sent to my application that would kill the system tray icon but the application doesn't quit.

Comment: I also think this is a Restart Manager bug. I have the same problem restarting `explorer.exe` to install a shell extension, and it fails with the exact same error messages. `explorer.exe` is obviously RM-compatible and the operation runs smoothly on Windows 7 (I just tested it). I’ve also tried `MSIDISABLERMRESTART=0 MSIRMSHUTDOWN=2 MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL=0` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8361988/3091755) with no luck. I assume the Windows 10 Restart Manager is simply broken under many circumstances.